Wifi connection fails during updates (Kubuntu 24.04)
<excuse the double spacing in this post, but it seems to be the only way to preserve new lines on this site>
I have a new PC with Windows 11 pre installed on a 2TB SSD, all working perfectly.
I added Kubuntu 24.04 as dual boot on a 50G partition of a second 2TB SSD.
Everything seemed to be working on this installation until I tried to run the post-install updates.
Everytime I try via the GUI, the wi-fi neteork connection drops out immediately.
There is no error message or notification, according to the network panel the connection is still active, but if I try to ping the router at it's IP address it's unreachable.
The only way I can get the connection back is restarting the computer.
I tried going through the process using commands in a terminal.
The connection stays up long enough to get the list of updates with
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
214 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

and
apt list --upgradable
and
sudo apt-get upgrade
get's all the way to
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
But during the Get: operations the download eventually fails with the error
Connection timed out [IP: 2620:2d:40001::102 80]
and I can no longer ping the router
As a work-around I used the 'Err: X http//...' output to make a list of urls to the updates,
then made this list into an html file, then opened the file in Firefox (after restarting) then
downloaded each update manually.
It took a while to get throuigh the list because the connection would drop out after so many downloads (more about that later). But eventually I had a folder full of the packages and I used
sudo dpkg -i /home/admin/Downloads/*.deb
to run them.
Unfortunately none of these updates fixed the network problem.
Re. the drop-out behaviour:
The drop-out is not intermittant - it only happens during downloads and it does not come back by itself.
Once I had the files downloaded I was able to look at when the connection failed.
I assumed it would be after so many bytes of data, but I found that sometimes it broke after about 9Gb and sometimes after about 50Gb.
As I said, there is no such problem in Windows - in fact for the largest of the updates (454Mb), which failed repeatedly in Kubuntu, I just downloaded it in a Windows session then picked up the file in Kubuntu.
Also when the connectio fails I can stll access the wi-fi on other computers.
Also as I said, the system seems unaware of the connection failure. I configured
Notifications -- System Settings  ->  Network Management  ->  Events
to log every message to a text file, but (apart from a test) not one message was recorded, ever.
Disable/Enable in the network panel leads to 'No available connection' and a 'Connection 'XXXXX' deactivated  notification. The wi-fi connection is still listed and unchanged in the Connections -- System Settings section.
And at this point I am out of ideas.
Does anyone know why this might be happening, or have any suggestions about tracing the connection failure?
Is there a way to reset the network connection without restarting?
Cheers
<< Edit 22 Aug 14:10 >>
Thanks for your replies guys
I would have got back to you earlier but after posting my question my Windows had a BSOD wth CRITICAL PROCESS DIED and the only way I could fix it was a system restore to before I installed Kubuntu, which meant that I lost the Grub installation so I couldn't boot to Kubuntu
To fix that I had to install boot-repair, which broke the wi-fi during download, which gave me the chance to try out the IPv6 idea.
The interface wasn't quite the same as your instructions waltinator. I did it as follows:
Setttings -> Network -> XXXX -> IPv6 tab
Method: Automatic -> Disabled
[ Apply ]
This seemed to fix the boot-repair download drop-out (in Try Ubuntu). But when I did the same back in my real Kubuntu install, the Update via GUI failed again, about 80% through 'Fetching updates... '
Again, pinging the router fails.
In answer to your post amar, the installation was fresh, not an upgrade, and below is the result of lshw.
Note - I ran this After changing the IPv6 settiing, but there's no mention of ipv in the text, so I don't know if that matters.
Thanks again for your responses.
sudo lshw -c network
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 05
   serial: 9c:6b:00:62:0d:5f
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:55 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f6c00000-f6c0ffff memory:f6c10000-f6c13fff

*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: wlp5s0
   version: 10
   serial: f0:b6:1e:a3:2c:f3
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=29.198743027.0 3168-29.ucode ip=192.168.1.212 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:120 memory:f6b00000-f6b01fff

<< Edit 25 Aug 10:18 >>
OK. I ran  journalctl -b | grep wifi
nothing stood out, so I started a continous ping to the router, then started Discover -> update on the 1.7K (linux-generic 6.8.1.41.41) entry.
The update got to about 14% then it and the ping stopped.
Then I ran  journalctl -b | grep wifi  a second time (output below)
The first fourteen entries were the same as the first time I ran journalctl,
Re. the entries at 25 09:32:00 - this may be something to do with KDE Wallet, which popped up one day without my asking and which I eventually got rid of. NOTE - this was long After the wi-fi drop issue.
Output of   journalctl -b | grep wifi
(Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx is anonymised computer name, 'NGb' is the wi-fi connection)
journalctl -b | grep wifi
Aug 25 09:31:55 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Aug 25 09:31:55 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x0, cnv-id 0x0 wfpm id 0x0
Aug 25 09:31:55 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: PCI dev 24fb/2110, rev=0x220, rfid=0xd55555d5
Aug 25 09:31:55 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.198743027.0 3168-29.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
Aug 25 09:31:55 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3168, REV=0x220
Aug 25 09:31:55 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: base HW address: f0:b6:1e:a3:2c:f3, OTP minor version: 0x0
Aug 25 09:31:55 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
Aug 25 09:31:56 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx NetworkManager[1240]:   [1724574716.6904] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-
devices.conf, netplan.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Aug 25 09:31:56 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx NetworkManager[1240]:   [1724574716.7063] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.5/0000:05:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver iwlwifi)
Aug 25 09:31:56 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx NetworkManager[1240]:   [1724574716.7096] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Aug 25 09:31:57 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0
Aug 25 09:32:00 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx NetworkManager[1240]:   [1724574720.7363] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'NGb' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 25 09:32:00 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx NetworkManager[1240]:   [1724574720.7375] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'NGb' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Aug 25 09:32:00 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx NetworkManager[1240]:   [1724574720.7984] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "NGb"
<< started Discover update here >>
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: WARNING: CPU: 11 PID: 1240 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2237 __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a0/0x1b0 [iwlwifi]
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer qrtr cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common amdgpu
snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg iwlmvm snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep edac_mce_amd mac80211 snd_pcm btusb btrtl
kvm_amd btintel snd_seq_midi btbcm amdxcp libarc4 snd_seq_midi_event btmtk drm_exec snd_rawmidi kvm gpu_sched drm_buddy snd_seq drm_suballoc_helper iwlwifi drm_ttm_helper bluetooth ttm snd_seq_device snd_timer
drm_display_helper ecdh_generic cec irqbypass snd ecc rc_core cfg80211 wmi_bmof rapl i2c_algo_bit soundcore k10temp i2c_piix4 ccp joydev input_leds mac_hid msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore nfnetlink dmi_sysfs
ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic xor raid6_pq libcrc32c dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul usbhid polyval_clmulni hid polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel nvme
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: RIP: 0010:__iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a0/0x1b0 [iwlwifi]
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel:  ? __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a0/0x1b0 [iwlwifi]
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel:  ? __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a0/0x1b0 [iwlwifi]
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel:  iwl_pcie_enqueue_hcmd+0x68b/0xe60 [iwlwifi]
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel:  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0xa8/0x370 [iwlwifi]
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel:  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel:  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x74/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000000: 24fb8086 00100000 02800010 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 21108086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000040: 00020010 10008ec0 001b0c10 0546e811 10110000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000005 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000080: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000000 00804005 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000100: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00002000 00002000 00000014 40001001
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000120: 0000000f f6b00460 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000140: 14c10003 ffa32cf3 f0b61eff 15410018 00000000 0001001e 00f01e1f 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00002000 00002000 00000014 40001001
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 00000020: 0000000f f6b00460 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:03.5) config registers:
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 00000000: 14db1022 00100407 06040000 00810010 00000000 00000000 00050500 200001f1
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 00000020: f6b0f6b0 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000050 00000000 001200ff
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 00000040: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c8035801 00000000 0142a010 00008022
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 00000060: 00002900 05737815 70110042 00042580 01400000 00010018 00000000 007319ff
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 00000080: 00000006 0180003e 00010041 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 000000a0: 0081c005 fee00000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 000000c0: 0000c80d 14531022 a8030008 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 000000e0: 00000000 9fff27fc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 00000100: 2701000b 01010001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 00000140: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 00000160: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 00000180: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 000001a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 000001c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 000001e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:03.5: 00000200: 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 25 09:36:31 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
Aug 25 09:36:37 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
Aug 25 09:36:38 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Queue 10 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [217, 229] HW [90, 90] FH TRB=0x05a5a5a5a
Aug 25 09:36:43 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
Aug 25 09:36:49 Xxxx-XxxxXxxxi-Lnx kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
<< 25 more lines like above until I Ctrl-C'd the ping >>
<< Edit 25 Aug 13:35 >>
Let's start with the easy one -
System Settings -> Driver Manager  [Relaunch Driver Manager]
Searching . . .
No additional drivers available
(about that - is there a way to see what driver is being used for my wifi card?)
Next the '... older kernel version?' post.
I tried searching the grub-mkconfig for kernels as shown, but the result was quite different:
sudo grub-mkconfig | grep -iE "menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux" | awk '{print i++ " : "$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-31-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
-
This lines up with the GRUB menu that opens on (re)starting Kubuntu:
GNU GRUB version 2.12
Kubuntu
Advanced options for Kubuntu
Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi)
Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi, serial console)
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme1np1)
UEFI Firmware Settings
-
Advanced options for Kubuntu:
Kubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-31-generic
Kubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-31-generic (recovery mode)
-
Am I right in thinking that there is only one (the current) kernel version available?
<< Edit 18 Sept >>
OK, I was finally able to test the updates via a hard-wired Ethernet connection to the WiFi router.
The Discover - Updates method successfully found, downloaded and installed all 38 updates.
I was delayed because of another experiment I did after finding that the WiFi card in my Mini PC is not supported under Linux.
I tried connecting a 20 year old NetGear USB WiFi adapter (which is fully supported).
The GUI Discover - Updates method still failed instantly on the smallest (1.7K) update, but the terminal method
sudo apt-get upgrade
was able to find, download and install the full list of updates without a problem (unfortunately this meant that I had to wait for some more updates to test the Ethernet connection on).
I have read about a program called NDISwrapper, which apperently enables Linux to access hardware using Windows drivers. I'm planning to give this a try, but the installation and setup looks a bit complicated so it might take a while.
Even so, my test with the NetGear WiFi adapter (specifically the difference between cmd line and Discover updates) seems to suggest that there is more to the problem than hardware support.

Did you upgrade to Kubuntu 24.04 or was it fresh install? and run sudo lshw -c network in a terminal and edit your question with the results, do not put the answer in comment.

OK, I thought I had edited the post yesterday, but apparently I also had to approve my own edit, which I needed 'reputation points' for, or something? So maybe I've done that now.

Enable IPv6, it seems that your wireless is erratic, try disabling powersave on the wifi Run `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf´, and change the value of wifi.powersave to 2, save it by CTRL+x and press enter to exit and test if that solvers the issue.

If it works tell me and I write an answer.

Nope, sorry -
I did the above (inc. re-opening the .conf file to check that it was updated).
Then I opened the Discover -> See updates... interface and un-selected everything except the smallest file (1.7K)
But it failed at 7%, router down
Also tried the same update after restarting - same effect, except failed at 0%
One thing that occured to me, the .deb that files I have been downloading in Firefox are much bigger that 1.7K, and - while the drop-out does still happen eventually - the Discover update seems to fail much sooner.

run journalctl -b | grep wifi -b limitits it to from boot and b -1  gives you last boot see if there is something there.

Try booting with an earlier kernel, just  boot do not change any thing else https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version#:~:text=immediately%20after%20the%20motherboard%20%2F%20computer

Also in Kubuntu go to System Settings find Driver Manager and launch it, see if there is any driver or updates for your wifi.

no there is always 2, right now for Kubuntu I downloade kernel 6.8.0.41, I suggest you connect your computer with a network line to your rourter and fully update it then disconnect the line and check your wifi

Or do a reinstall and update it directly

The IP address (2620:2d:40001::102) is an IPv6 address. unfotunately, your upstream network doesn't support IPv6.
To disable IPv6, open Settings->Network->Your interface->IPv6 Tab, and UNcheck "Enable IPv6". Save your change, then turn the interface OFF, 1breath, ON, to ensure the new setting takes effect.

Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.

No, sorry Waltinator. As far as I can tell the Ipv6 setting did not make any difference.
